# Create a trigger to check specific columns

Tags: sql-server

I would like to have a trigger that validates if a column has a specific value, I know I should use foreign keys for that, but in this case I can't so I would like to create a kind of generic trigger to validate a specific column if a table:

For example I have this query returns basic info that I need and for the table name by convention I add the string 'TypeId' and I put it in a variable @Column, when I try to check if that column was changed, the IF UPDATE gives me an error. Is there any way to validate that this column was changed using this approach?

```
    SELECT @schema = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_id),
           @table = OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) 
      FROM sys.triggers 
     WHERE object_id = @@PROCID

     DECLARE @Column NVARCHAR(50) = @table + N'TypeId'

     IF UPDATE (@Column)              
     BEGIN
        PRINT '->' + @table + '<-'   
     END
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the column name as a variable approach will work.  You could use dynamic sql to generate a trigger template for each table.  This would hard-code the column name and allow the `IF UPDATE()` statement to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're being too vague in your description for me to offer any real advice. You've ruled out foreign keys (for some vague reason) but are apparently able to create triggers. Have you also ruled out e.g. check constraints? Triggers should be a last resort for enforcing integrity when there are many tools at our disposal that are more specific.

Comment: ok, check constraints. thanks!

Comment: now my question is: can I create a check constraint for a specific column that should have specific value stored in another table? like for example I have the Employee_Type_Id and this type should be only 1,2 or 3 based on this three values stored in another table?

Comment: Isn't that a foreign Key?